# Pass column field in stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure in MYSQL. I am passing 6 inputs to the stored procedure. I have 260 columns having column name finewt_1,finewt_2,finewt_3....finewt_260.

My stored procedure is:

```
Create procedure GetImg($r35 double,
r36 double,
$r37 double, 
r38 double,
$r39 double, 
r40 double)

begin

select img_id,img_path,
((pow((r36-finewt_$r35),2))+(pow((r38-finewt_$r37),2))+(pow((r40-finewt_$r39),2))) as distance from tbl_fine

end
```

When I try to call this stored procedure from php it gives me an error saying finewt_$r35 not found. I want to make the calculation such that if suppose $r35=50 I want (r36-finewt_50). How can I do this? This is just a small portion of my sql statement I have to do this for 30,000+ images so I do not want to use another select statement. How can I solve this problem?

I tried using dynamic sql also I get the error message:

```
Unknown column 'finewt_13' in 'field list'
```

My dynamic sql is:

```
    Create procedure GetImg($r35 double,
    r36 double,
    $r37 double, 
    r38 double,
    $r39 double, 
    r40 double)

    begin

    Set @s=CONCAT('select img_id,img_path,
    ((pow((r36-',finewt_$r35,'),2))+(pow((r38-',finewt_$r37,'),2))+(pow((r40-finewt_$r39),2))) as distance from tbl_fine');
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;


    end
```

When I try this:

```
CONCAT(......(pow((r36-finewt_',$r35,'),2))+(pow((r38-finewt_',$r37,')),2)+(pow((r40-finewt_',$r39,'),2)).....
```

I get the error:

```
Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'pow'
```

Comment: What about doing it in PHP, not in a stored procedure

Comment: From PHP I can do this but I am trying to do it using stored procedure so

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate the string,

```
CONCAT(r36,'-finewt_',$r35)
```

edit,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_my_proc`(reqdTable varchar(50))

set @table_name = reqdTable;
SET @sql_text = concat('SELECT ..blah blah' FROM',@table_name,'WHERE blah blah');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: That will only work if you make your entire query in dynamic SQL. In normal SQL queries, it is not possible to specify the table name or column name using variables.

Comment: If you build the full query string it will work, ive updated with an example from a quick google search.